# Option to disable popup after voting to close

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I am sure most users who have voted to close a question have been annoyed by the popup:

---

[image: Vote to close popup]

---

To an experienced user, this gets annoying (and unnecessary) over time - not to mention redundant, as the number of close votes are shown by the `close` button anyway (here, as `close(3)`). These popups are present in other places of the UI as well after certain actions have been performed.

**Option Possibilities**

1. An option to disable popups that have already been presented to you. In other words, only popups that you have never seen before will be shown only once.
2. A "Don't display this message again." checkbox on each popup.

Comment: Is it *that* annoying? I'll just close the tab and move on.

Comment: It's not so much annoying as it is unnecessary.

Comment: True. Stack Exchange has a history of not adding configuration options, so good luck with the proposal :)

Comment: It's not modal, so you don't _have_ to click it. Usually, you just want to go to a different page after voting to close anyway, so just ignore it.

Comment: Maybe, it would be better to show that popup *N first times*, say 5 or 10.

Comment: @hammar: Which could also raise the question: why bother showing the popup (or the click to dismiss link) if you are going to navigate away anyway?

Comment: @EvanMulawski: It serves a purpose in teaching new users how the system works, and how many votes are required to close a question, so I don't think it should be removed completely.

Comment: @hammar: I didn't suggest it be removed completely, just an option to disable them after they have been displayed at least once, generally or individually.

Answer (score 3):

I agree wholeheartedly with hammar's comment:

> It serves a purpose in teaching new users how the system works, and how many votes are required to close a question, so I don't think it should be removed completely.

Thus, the best solution is to stop showing this pop-up after a user gets to a certain reputation level, when we can reasonably assume that they already know and understand how the system works.

There are already lots of other pop-ups and bells that stop appearing after a certain reputation level, like the prompt to leave a comment when downvoting or the suggestion to share your answer to a question on a social networking service. There's no reason that this can't be implemented similarly. After a user achieves, say, 10k reputation, we would stop showing the pop-up explaining how close voting works.

Then again, I could easily be persuaded that this isn't necessary at all. I cast a lot of close votes and thus see this pop-up a lot, but since I understand how the system works, I just ignore it. I don't bother to close it, since it isn't modal and doesn't interfere with my workflow. In fact, it fades away automatically after a certain period of time, which means I don't have to interact with it at all. slhck echoes these sentiments in a comment:

> Is it *that* annoying? I'll just close the tab and move on.

Precisely.

Comment: Maybe don't use a reputation threshold there, but take into account how often you've voted to close. I know plenty of high-rep users whom I've never seen in the "closed by" message.